# How to "properly" avoid race conditions over reading/writting files when using NodeJs alongside a C++ software?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, race-condition

I have a simple interface that takes some input values, sends them through an AXIOS post to an ExpressJS server which writes them to a file. That same file gets checked for new values at a random interval of times by another piece of C++ software.
The way I've went was to create `.lock` files associated with the `.txt` files that I want to read/write.
So the C++ opens the `.lock` file to get a file descriptor, then it locks it using that file descriptor. If the lock is succesfull then it proceeds to open, write and close the `.txt` file. Afterwards it unlocks and closes the `.lock`.

Now I have done the same thing on the ExpressJS side of things:

```
app.post("/dhcpIP", function(req, res) {
  if (req.body.constructor === Object && Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
    return res.status(500).send("ERROR: Inputs are empty !");
  }

  let fileText = req.body;
  console.log("fileText: ");
  console.log(fileText);

  const dhcpcd_lock = fs.openSync(dhcpcd_lock_path, "w+");

  flock(dhcpcd_lock, "ex", (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error("Could not lock file.");

    console.log("dhcpcd_lock is locked.");

    const write_to_file = fileText;
    fs.writeFile(
      path.join(configFilesLocation, "/configuration.txt"),
      write_to_file,
      (error) => {
        if (error) return console.error(error);
        console.log("configuration.txt was saved");

        flock(dhcpcd_lock, "un", (error) => {
          if (error) return console.error(error);          

          console.log("File is unlocked.");
          res.sendStatus(200);

          fs.closeSync(dhcpcd_lock);
        });
      }
    );
  });
});
```

As you can see I've nested the code inside the callbacks of the async functions:

- `fs.writeFile()` is inside `flock('ex')` callback
- `flock('un')` is inside `fs.writeFile()` callback
- `res.sendStatus(200);` and `fs.closeSync(dhcpcd_lock);` are inside `flock('un')` callback

I don't know if this is the proper way of doing things because it's my first time doing this.
I don't know if it's OK or not to use `openSync` and `closeSync`to open and close the lock file and have the other functions be asynchronous (`flock`, `fs.writeFile`).
Should I have used the async `open` and then nested the code in its callback and finally use the async `close` ?

How does the above code changes  if I have to write two files in the same `app.post()` handler ?
Will I have to do it all synchronous ?